# PHP printf and gettext

Tags: php, printf, translation, gettext

I guess it's a quite simple one, but i'm beginning with gettext and printf, and it's a little bit confusing for me ...

I have the following line

```
printf(__('Je confirme avoir lu et accepté les 
<a href="%1$s" target="_blank" class="underline">mentions légales et règle
s des cookies</a>, ainsi que les <a href="%2$s" class="underline" 
target="_blank">CGV</a>','contact'),$ROUTES['legal'],$ROUTES['terms'])
```

The string is correctly translated but the `%1$s`and `%2$s`stays as-is and are not replaced by the corresponding values. So i obtain a link like this one `https://www.example.com/%2$s` where i should have something like `https://www.example.com/mypage.html`

Note that __() function is taking the string to translate as first argument, and text domain as second one, which is quite efficient when i'm not coupling with printf...

Maybe it has something to do the simple/double quotes inside the translated string? Any ideas?

Comment: why is there a function named `__`? That seems foolish. It doesn't help anything

Comment: @Martin default WordPress functionality, I’m guessing? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/

Comment: @Martin It is a translation function in WordPress

Comment: ```__()``` function has been created because different text domains exist on the website, so the function defines in which text domain the current string to translate is to find. Inspired from WP yes, but not the exact same one

Comment: Found the answer : 
My ```__()``` function uses 'echo' by default, but in this case needs to 'return'. Thanks for brainstorm !